# How to detect ellipse in image with Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, detect, ellipse

How to detect ellipse in image with Matlab and eliminate the redundant part of the image?

Answer (score 2):

It highly depends on the noise in your image and so on.

One thing to try is to detect edges with `edge`: 
`BW = edge(I,'canny')`,

then extract connected component with `bwlabel`.

then try to fit an ellipse to each component. For instance, you can use [this toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15125).

and you keep edges with low reconstruction error.